# Javascript while loop conditional not working

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, while-loop

I have an object teams and a string sharelink

```
var teams = {
  team1 : {
    roster : []
  },
  team2 : {
    roster : []
  },
};
var sharelink = "localhost:5000/team1=9234&5678&9999&6585team2=15566";
```

And I want to parse through the sharelink for each team's substring delimited by "t" and have gotten it to work with the following code:

```
for(var team in teams){
  var start = sharelink.search(team) + team.length + 1;
  var end = start + 1;
  while(sharelink[end]){
    if(sharelink[end] == "t"){
      break;
    }
    end++;
  }
  console.log(sharelink.slice(start, end));
  /*
  returns "9234&5678&9999&6585" on the first iteration and
  "15566" on the second and final time through just like I want it to  
  */
}
```

It also works fine when I just have the while loop by itself just to get team1's substring

```
var start = sharelink.search("team1") + "team1".length + 1;
  var end = start + 1;
  while(sharelink[end] != "t"){
    end++;
  }
console.log(sharelink.slice(start, end));
//returns "9234&5678&9999&6585" just as intended
```

But the following code goes into an infinite loop.

```
for(var team in teams){
  var start = sharelink.search(team) + team.length + 1;
  var end = start + 1;
  while(sharelink[end] != "t"){
    end++;
  }
}
```

Why?

Comment: It'll be an infinite loop because once you run past the end of the string `sharelink[end]` will be `undefined`, which is not equal to `"t"`, so the while loop condition stays true forever. Seems to me this could be done with regex rather than building your own parser.

Comment: Try `while (end < sharelink.length && sharelink[end] != 't')`

Comment: Why don't you have a delimiter like `&` before `team2=15566`?

Comment: Would help if you had a properly uri encoded string to start with

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. The real string is supposed to have an & before That was my mistake